# get app link from play store before publishing?

Tags: google-play, ionic3

I'm making an app with ionic v3 and I wanna create a link that take you to the play store to download the app, I'm trying this: "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packagename" but how can I get the package name from Ionic v3 ?
or exist another way to do this.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `id` and `android-packageName` in your `config.xml` which is exactly what you are looking for.

docs: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the **config.xml** file and you will get both the `id` and the `android package name` in that file.

*Reference*: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html